# How to configure SSL in WSDL First CXF Framework web service?

Tags: ssl, wsdl, cxf, top-down

I am new to CXF framework. Recently successfully created webservices using CXF and Spring Endpoint. I am using WSDL first approach. Can you please suggest how to use SSL(https) for web services. I have idea about truststore and keystore. I am using Apache Tomcat server.
below is my ApplicationContext.xml -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd"
default-autowire="byName">

 <!-- Service endpoint -->
<jaxws:endpoint id="CalculatorWebService"
        implementorClass="com.web.calculator.service.CalculatorContractImpl"
        implementor="#CalculatorImpl"
        address="/CalculatorWS">
</jaxws:endpoint>

<bean id="CalculatorImpl" class="com.web.calculator.service.CalculatorContractImpl"/>
```

I believe I need to make some configuration entries for truststore here and similarly some configuration for keystore in client side in some xml. Also I think I need some Passwordcallback class for using keystores.

Can you please help me with the configurations that has to be made to enable SSL.

Your help is truly appreciated...

Thanks...

Comment: You can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755293/apache-cxf-wsdl-download-via-ssl-tls.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is great tutorial how to set up everything you need with SSL in your CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html). Please refer to section `Configuring SSL Support`.
And do not forget to enable `https` in your tomcat. The full "how to do this" is provided [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html). I assume that you did not try anything yet. All you need to do just follow these steps because there is everything explained very clear.