# Apache CXF wsdl download via SSL/TLS

Tags: java, ssl, wsdl, cxf, client-certificates

I have a cxf service running at

```
https://localhost:8443/services/MyService?wsdl
```

with client certificate required. The WSDL is not important here.

I am able to invoke the service when I remove the client certificate or https requirement.

The service and client classes were generated with cxf wsdl2java utility.

Here is MyService.class:

```java
package com.mycompany;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;

/**
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 2.7.3 2013-03-29T13:59:37.423-03:00 Generated source version: 2.7.3
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "MyService", wsdlLocation = "myservice.wsdl", targetNamespace = "http://server/schemas/services")
public class MyService extends Service {

    public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

    public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://server/schemas/services", "MyService");
    public final static QName MyServicePort = new QName("http://server/schemas/services", "MyServicePort");
    static {
        URL url = MyService.class.getResource("myservice.wsdl");
        if (url == null) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyService.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "myservice.wsdl");
        }
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public MyService(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE);
    }

    public MyService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public MyService() {
        super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return returns EncaminharMensagemPortType
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "MyServicePort")
    public MyServicePortType getMyServicePort() {
        return super.getPort(MyServicePort, MyServicePortType.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param features
     *            A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy. Supported features not in the
     *            <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
     * @return returns EncaminharMensagemPortType
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "MyServicePort")
    public MyServicePortType getMyServicePort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(MyServicePort, MyServicePortType.class, features);
    }

}
```

Here is my client without client certificate requirement: (that work fine)

```java
package com.mycompany;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import com.mycompany.IdHolder;
import com.mycompany.MyDataObject;

public class CxfClientSslTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://server/schemas/services", "MyService");
            URL wsdlURL = new URL("https://localhost:8443/services/MyService?wsdl");
            MyService ss = new MyService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
            MyServicePortType port = ss.getMyServicePort();

            IdHolder mensagem = new IdHolder();
            mensagem.setId(1L);
            MyDataObject dataObject = port.getById(mensagem);

            System.out.println("Id: " + dataObject.getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my client send his certificate:

```java
package com.mycompany;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;

public class CxfClientSslTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://server/schemas/services", "MyService");
            URL wsdlURL = new URL("https://localhost:8443/services/MyService?wsdl");
            MyService ss = new MyService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
            MyServicePortType port = ss.getMyServicePort();

            tslIt(port);

            IdHolder mensagem = new IdHolder();
            mensagem.setId(1L);
            MyDataObject dataObject = port.getById(mensagem);

            System.out.println("Id: " + dataObject.getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void tslIt(MyServicePortType port) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException,
            UnrecoverableKeyException {
        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
        HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

        TLSClientParameters tlsClientParameters = http.getTlsClientParameters();

        KeyStore keyStore = getKeyStore();
        KeyStore trustStore = getTrustStore();

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "123456".toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] keyMgrs = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
        tlsClientParameters.setKeyManagers(keyMgrs);

        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        tlsClientParameters.setTrustManagers(trustManagers);

        tlsClientParameters.setDisableCNCheck(true);
    }

    public static KeyStore getKeyStore() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
        URL keyStoreUrl = CxfClientSslTest.class.getResource("/certs/client.jks");
        File keystoreFile = new File(keyStoreUrl.getPath());
        if (!keystoreFile.exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("keystore doesn't exists: " + keystoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        InputStream keystoreInput = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
        keystore.load(keystoreInput, "changeit".toCharArray());
        keystoreInput.close();
        return keystore;
    }

    public static KeyStore getTrustStore() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
        URL trustStoreUrl = CxfClientSslTest.class.getResource("/certs/client-trust.jks");
        File trustStoreFile = new File(trustStoreUrl.getPath());
        if (!trustStoreFile.exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("truststore doesn't exists: " + trustStoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        InputStream trustStoreInput = new FileInputStream(trustStoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
        trustStore.load(trustStoreInput, "changeit".toCharArray());
        trustStoreInput.close();
        return trustStore;
    }

}
```

The TLS configuration both from client and server were checked and are ok. But when I run the program I get this:

```java
Information: Can not initialize the default wsdl from myservice.wsdl
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:98)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
    at com.mycompany.MyService.<init>(MyService.java:36)
    at com.mycompany.CxfClientSslTest.main(CxfClientSslTest.java:32)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:100)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:199)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:147)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'https://localhost:8443/services/MyService?wsdl'.: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:205)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:98)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1337)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:998)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1294)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1321)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:523)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1296)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:653)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:799)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:240)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:300)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:208)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:347)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:203)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1319)
    ... 30 more
```

I can see that the problem is happening before my https configuration get done, when cxf tries to download the wsdl.

I made a research on how to make cxf use that https configuration to download the wsdl. It take me a lot of time, but I can't find the answer out there.

So my question is: how to make cxf use the https configuration to download the wsdl?

Please, I have the answer already and I intend to put it here. So, if you don't have a good answer, or better the answer, please don't post one.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Please read more about SO policies. More specific about [etiquette](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette) and [its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of research on the web without success, I decide it is time to debug the cxf API. That is one of the points of open source, right?

So I found out that cxf don't download directly the wsdl. It delegates that to wsdl4j through the call of

```java
javax.wsdl.xml.WSDLReader.readWSDL(javax.wsdl.xml.WSDLLocator)
```

which calls

```java
javax.wsdl.xml.WSDLLocator.getBaseInputSource()
```

which calls

```java
org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.ResourceManagerWSDLLocator.getInputSource(String, String)
```

because ResourceManagerWSDLLocator were the WSDLLocator of the first method call.

ResourceManagerWSDLLocator.getInputSource first line is:

```java
InputStream ins = bus.getExtension(ResourceManager.class).getResourceAsStream(importLocation);
```

Now as ResourceManager is a extension of xcf's Bus, and you can add more ResourceResolver to it and the DefaultResourceManager (implements ResourceManager) will loop through all registered resolvers and will use the first one resolving a non-null value, you just need add a ResourceResolver to the ResourceManager.

My final and working client application is:

```java
package com.mycompany;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.BusFactory;
import org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.resource.ResourceManager;
import org.apache.cxf.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class CxfClientSslTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Bus bus = BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus();
            ResourceManager extension = bus.getExtension(ResourceManager.class);

            extension.addResourceResolver(new ResourceResolver() {
                @Override
                public <T> T resolve(String resourceName, Class<T> resourceType) {
                    System.out.println("resourceName: " + resourceName + " - resourceType: " + resourceType);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public InputStream getAsStream(String name) {
                    try {
                        if (!name.startsWith("https")) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SslUtil.getSslSocketFactory();
                        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
                        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", 8443, sslSocketFactory));

                        final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry), httpParams);

                        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(name);
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
                        return response.getEntity().getContent();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            });

            QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://server/schemas/services", "MyService");
            URL wsdlURL = new URL("https://localhost:8443/services/MyService?wsdl");
            MyService ss = new MyService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
            MyServicePortType port = ss.getMyServicePort();

            tslIt(port);

            IdHolder mensagem = new IdHolder();
            mensagem.setId(1L);
            MyDataObject dataObject = port.getById(mensagem);

            System.out.println("Id: " + dataObject.getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void tslIt(MyServicePortType port) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException,
            UnrecoverableKeyException {
        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
        HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

        TLSClientParameters tlsClientParameters = http.getTlsClientParameters();

        KeyStore keyStore = getKeyStore();
        KeyStore trustStore = getTrustStore();

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "123456".toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] keyMgrs = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
        tlsClientParameters.setKeyManagers(keyMgrs);

        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        tlsClientParameters.setTrustManagers(trustManagers);

        tlsClientParameters.setDisableCNCheck(true);
    }

    public static KeyStore getKeyStore() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
        URL keyStoreUrl = CxfClientSslTest.class.getResource("/certs/client.jks");
        File keystoreFile = new File(keyStoreUrl.getPath());
        if (!keystoreFile.exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("keystore doesn't exists: " + keystoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        InputStream keystoreInput = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
        keystore.load(keystoreInput, "changeit".toCharArray());
        keystoreInput.close();
        return keystore;
    }

    public static KeyStore getTrustStore() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
        URL trustStoreUrl = CxfClientSslTest.class.getResource("/certs/client-trust.jks");
        File trustStoreFile = new File(trustStoreUrl.getPath());
        if (!trustStoreFile.exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("truststore doesn't exists: " + trustStoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        InputStream trustStoreInput = new FileInputStream(trustStoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
        trustStore.load(trustStoreInput, "changeit".toCharArray());
        trustStoreInput.close();
        return trustStore;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is older but it looks like CXF address this issue here:  http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html looks like they have a special conduit for SSL secured WSDL's.  "If your service endpoint uses an SSL WSDL location (i.e., "https://xxx?wsdl"), you can configure the http conduit to pick up the SSL configuration by using a hardcoded http conduit name of "{http://cxf.apache.org/}TransportURIResolver.http-conduit". The specific HTTP conduit name or a reg-ex expression can still be used."

Answer (score 1):

I think the standard way in *apache cxf* is to set-up an `http conduit` in your cxf.xml refering to your jks keystore:

```
<http:conduit id="{Namespace}PortName.http-conduit"> 
<http:tlsClientParameters>
...
<sec:trustManagers>
  <sec:keyStore type="JKS"
                password="StorePass"
                file="certs/truststore.jks"/>
</sec:trustManagers>
 ...
</http:tlsClientParameters>
</http:conduit>
```

More information here: [Configuring SSL support](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-ConfiguringSSLSupport%20ConfiguringSSLSupport)

Comment: I don't know if you read the entire question and answer or it may be not clear but I'll try to explain. The http conduit is the way, no doubt about that. But the standard SSL config way is used only to service invocation. It is not used to download the WSDL before service invocation, because CXF is not downloading the WSDL, wsl4j is. This method overrides the default wsdl4j configuration for SSL.

Comment: hmm, you're right: I've debugged this code and as you said the http conduit is not even used to resolve the WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

```
tlsClientParameters.setUseHttpsURLConnectionDefaultSslSocketFactory(false);
```

Above line is required to disable default SslSocketFactory (which will ignore the keyStore and trustStore configured in tlsClientParamters)

Comment: You miss the point. ResourceManager doesn't use TlsClientParameters values to start a http connection. And it doesn't make sense to change the default ssl socket factory config because it can broke another app.

Comment: @DiogoSantana you are right, my solution is focusing on the hand_shake failure exception when doing the retrieving data request.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/15755512/19664676
by @DiogoSantana

One can simply add HTTPConduitConfigurer extension to bus like this.

```
package com.mycompany;

import com.mycompany.IdHolder;
import com.mycompany.MyDataObject;
import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.BusFactory;
import org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduitConfigurer;

import java.net.URL;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class CxfClientSslTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bus bus = BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus();
        bus.setExtension(new HTTPConduitConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void configure(String name, String address, HTTPConduit c) {
                //crate and configure sslcontext
                SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sslContext.init(getKeyManagers(), getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

                TLSClientParameters tls = new TLSClientParameters();
                //configure tls client params here
                tls.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
                //set tls client params
                c.setTlsClientParameters(tls);
            }
        }, HTTPConduitConfigurer.class);

        QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://server/schemas/services", "MyService");
        URL wsdlURL = new URL("https://localhost:8443/services/MyService?wsdl");
        MyService ss = new MyService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
        MyServicePortType port = ss.getMyServicePort();

        IdHolder mensagem = new IdHolder();
        mensagem.setId(1L);
        MyDataObject dataObject = port.getById(mensagem);

        System.out.println("Id: " + dataObject.getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found

Above exception happens When you create your self-signed certificate with your name,
To resolve this exception, you need to add `"localhost"` on the following step

```
What is your first and last name?
 [Unknown]:  localhost
```

Comment: Like I said, it is not a certificate problem. I checked that and I were able to connect to the server with client certificate directly via URLHTttpConnection. And I didn't say it was a self-signed certificate, which is not.